# Ошибка Allowed memory size

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Нужно вывести на сайт таблицу из PhpMyAdmin. Мне выдали пример кода, я отредактировал его на столько, на сколько мозгов хватило (я новичок). Но браузер выдал такую ошибку :

**"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1073741832 bytes) in C:\OpenServer\domains\UchProc\Show_stud.php on line 24"**

Как исправить эту ошибку, чтобы не лезть в настройки PHP ?

код php :

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Вывод сведений из таблиц базы "Trade" на My SQL</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BACKGROUND="Зима.jpg" LINK="WHITE" VLINK="WHITE">
      
     
    <?php
           Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 
      //Устанавливаем связь с базой.
      //require_once "Connect_BD.php";
      include "Connect_BD.php";
      //$c=mysqli_query('SET NAMES cp1251', "Connect_BD.php");
      

      //Получаем все данные таблицы.
      $r=mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM studenti')
        or die(mysqli_error());
      // Размещаем результат в массиве $data
      $data=array();
      while (($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) !== false)
      {
            $data[]=$row;
      }
      // Узнаем число записей в таблице.
      $rows=mysqli_num_rows($r);
      
    ?> 
      
      <TABLE border=4 cellspasing=15 bgcolor="WHITE" ALIGN="center">
      <COLGROUP  span=12 width="150">
      <CAPTION>  
      <FONT color="white"> 
      <H1>
      Список студентов
      </h1>
      </FONT> 
      </caption>    
      <TR><TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white"> Табельный номер </FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Фамилия</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Имя</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Отчество</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Факультет</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Курс</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Группа</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Пол</FONT>
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Дата рождения</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Рост</FONT> 
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Средний балл</FONT>
      <TH bgcolor="INDIGO"><FONT color="white">Доход</FONT>      
        <?php for  ($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++) {?>
      <TR ALIGN="center"><TD> <?php echo $data[$i]["Tab_stud"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Fam_stud"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Name_stud"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Otch_stud"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Fakult"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Kurs"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Gruppa"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Pol"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Data_Roj"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Rost"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Sr_ball"]?>
      <TD><?php echo $data[$i]["Doxod"]?>
          
       <?php }?>
      </table> 
     <!-- <BR>
     <BR>
     <BR>
      <BR>
       <BR>
        <BR>
      <BR ALIGN="center"> 
     <FONT color="white"> 
    <H2 ALIGN="center"><A HREF="Int_Mag.html"><I> ВОЗВРАТ</i></A></H2> 
    </FONT> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Код connect.php

```
<?php
  // Подключение к СУБД MySQL
  $host="localhost";
  $user="root";
  $pass="root";
  $db="uch_proc";
  //
  $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
?>
```

Comment: @Jean-Claude а если посмотреть на проблему не так прямолинейно? посмотреть внимательнее на код? подумать на один ход вперёд? может быть, тогда появится четвёртый способ, не такой дурацкий, как описанные в статье по ссылке?

Comment: Тут одна явная проблема, и одна вероятная. Явная - это то, что из базы выбираются сразу все записи. Так НИКОГДА не делают. Данные надо запрашивать небольшими порциями. Но с другой стороны, я сомневаюсь что в учебной базе лежат такие объемы, чтобы прямо положить сервер. И тут причиной может быть другая проблема. Если в таблице есть поля типа longblob, то во-первых, надо их выкинуть, потому что не может быть таких полей в таблице студентов. А во-вторых, обновить версию РНР

Answer (score -2):

Возникновение ошибки «Fatal error: Allowed memory size», связано с нехваткой оперативной памяти, необходимой для успешного выполнения скрипта на сайте. В случае возникновения данной ошибки, в большинстве случаев для устранения проблемы достаточно увеличить лимит оперативной памяти, выделяемой для выполнения скрипта на сайте. Ниже приведен полный текст данной ошибки, а так же описано как увеличить лимит оперативной памяти в панели управления хостингом ISPmanager.
https://bitte.net.ua/blog/oshibka-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size/

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Но я уже заходил на этот сайт. Я работаю через openserver и ispmanager'а у меня нет.

Comment: Мои милые маленькие друзья. А другие варианты, кроме как увеличить объем оперативной памяти, вам в голову никогда не приходили? Всё-таки, хорошо, что программисты не строят корабли. Ведь такой "специалист", если пассажиры на корабле не помещаются, просто будет увеличивать количество кают. пока корабль просто не потонет, со всем этим зоопарком на борту